# Are there any relatively mature RDF/OWL Persistence Frameworks I can use?

Tags: persistence, rdf, owl

I have looked at Elmo from openrdf.org, but it doesn't seem to support having object within another object.  E.g. Class Roof within the Class House and then allow persisting House object.

Is there any other fairly mature and better documented persistence framework out there for RDF/OWL data that will allow such operations?  Or if not, is there anything else at all out there?

Comment: I Think roof should be related to house and should not be within house?

Comment: Here are few other frameworks to have a look at: http://semanticweb.org/wiki/Tripresso

Comment: Yes, related to it, as an object property (a relation in other words), house hasRoof roof (that's what I actually meant by within (related to in RDF, but physically roof is part of house).

Comment: http://semanticweb.org/wiki/RDFReactor looks like it could get you half-way by providing you with a binding framework between RDFS/OWL and Java, and like a seems mature product. Related to this is TwoUse http://code.google.com/p/twouse/ which also looks promising.

Comment: Not worth a proper answer since it doesn't completely answer your question, but in terms of RDF stores I would suggest to stay away from SwiftOWLIM. A couple of months ago we ran into a few nasty bugs (losing data from the store) and came to the conclusion that it's not reliable yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [Empire](http://github.com/clarkparsia/Empire), it pretty closely implements the JPA spec and sounds like what you are looking for.

Also, fwiw, I believe Elmo can have composite mapped objects.

Answer (score 1):

- [RDF triple stores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore)
- Native OWL persistence:

  - OWLDB: http://owldb.sourceforge.net
  - Owlgres: http://pellet.owldl.com/owlgres/